# How to fill multiple arrays in R with one loop

Tags: r, arrays, for-loop, eval

I have many arrays to fill in R, each of which has a different name in a specific pattern. The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to refer to the array names as variables, so I can refer to them in a systematic way inside a loop.  They are created using this loop, for example.

```
for (i in c(40,45,50,55,57,60,65)){
  assign(paste0('hdd_',as.character(i),'_365_z'), rep(NA,365))}
```

I want to fill each of these arrays, which are now named like this: hdd_40_365_z, hdd_45_365_z, etc.

Let's say I want to fill each of these arrays using a simple function like this:

```
my_func <- function(value,doy){
  return(value * doy/2)}  # doy = doy or 1:365
```

I can write a loop to do this:

```
for (j in c(40,45,50,55,57,60,65)){
    for (k in 1:365){
        # try to fill arrays one day at a time
        paste0('hdd_',as.character(j),'_365_z')[k] <- my_func(j,k)}}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work.  I've tried using the following to do this, but it's not working.  There has to be a way to be able to do something like this, I would think, but I can't figure out the combination of eval, parse, as.name, or something else to do it.  Any help would be great.  Thank you.

```
eval(parse(text = paste0('hdd_',as.character(j),'_365_z')[k] <- my_func(j,k)))
```

Comment: Do they have to be separate variables? Often it is much easier to use a single `list()` and have each variable become a list element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, especially since you already know `assign`. Besides `assign`, the trick is to `get` the vector and `c`oncatenate the result of `my_func` to the existing vector.

We initialize the objects using `NULL` instead of `NA`,

```
for (i in c(40, 45, 50, 55, 57, 60, 65)) {
  assign(paste0('hdd_', as.character(i), '_365_z'), NULL)
}
```

and `c` each result.

```
for (j in c(40, 45, 50, 55, 57, 60, 65)) {
  for (k in 1:365) {
    # try to fill arrays one day at a time
    x <- paste0('hdd_', as.character(j), '_365_z')
    assign(x, c(get(x), my_func(j, k)))
  }
}
```

Gives:

```
lapply(mget(ls(pattern='hdd')), head)
# $hdd_40_365_z
# [1]  20  40  60  80 100 120
# 
# $hdd_45_365_z
# [1]  22.5  45.0  67.5  90.0 112.5 135.0
# 
# $hdd_50_365_z
# [1]  25  50  75 100 125 150
# 
# $hdd_55_365_z
# [1]  27.5  55.0  82.5 110.0 137.5 165.0
# 
# $hdd_57_365_z
# [1]  28.5  57.0  85.5 114.0 142.5 171.0
# 
# $hdd_60_365_z
# [1]  30  60  90 120 150 180
# 
# $hdd_65_365_z
# [1]  32.5  65.0  97.5 130.0 162.5 195.0
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you.